# How to run viewDidAppear

Tags: ios

I need to load some data into a view every time it is shown. The data changes, each time time view is shown,  so I figure I can load the data in the method viewDidAppear.  Unfortunately, I've found that viewDidAppear is not called each time the view is displayed.

The code that displays the view from any other view is....

```
[self clearView];
[self.view insertSubview:fifthViewController.view atIndex:4];
```

So I figured I could change it to the following to run viewDidAppear...

```
[[self.view insertSubview:fifthViewController.view atIndex: 4 viewDidAppear:YES];
```

Unfortunaely, this causes an error "bad receiver type 'void'

What do I need to do to insert the subview and also call viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the assistance with this question. 
I have settled on the addition of a viewDidAppear in the method that inserts the subview.

Below is the code that is working for me at this time.

In the .m file of the highest level view controller, the following code sets up the viewDidAppear call and then inserts the fifth subview.

```
-(IBAction) loadFifthView:(id)sender
{

[fifthViewController viewDidAppear:YES];  // sets up viewDidAppear


[self clearView];
[self.view insertSubview:fifthViewController.view atIndex:4];


}
```

With the above code snippet in place, the following code snippet, located in the .m file of the fifth view controller reports that it is working.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

NSLog(@" xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  inside viewDidAppear ");


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you show the view by modifying `ViewController.view` visibility directly, you won't get `viewDidAppear` message by that. You need to use `ViewController` method to display the view, e.g. push controller into `UINavigationController` or using `presentModalViewController` method. You can use the hack like calling `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` manually, but I don't like the idea.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you please tell me more about how that is done?